# creating a 3 by 4 matrix and adding the columns

Tags: python

> For this lab, you will work with two-dimensional lists in Python. Do
>   the following: Write a function that returns the sum of all the
>   elements in a specified column in a matrix using the following header:
>
> ```
> def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex)
> ```
>
> Write a function that displays the elements in a matrix row by row, where the values in each row are
>   displayed on a separate line (see the output below). Write a test
>   program (i.e., a main function) that reads a 3 X 4 matrix and displays
>   the sum of each column. Here is a sample run:
>
> Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 0: 2.5 3 4 1.5 Enter a 3-by-4 matrix
>   row for row 1: 1.5 4 2 7.5 Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 2: 3.5 1
>   1 2.5
>
> The matrix is
>   2.5 3.0 4.0 1.5
>   1.5 4.0 2.0 7.5
>   3.5 1.0 1.0 2.5
>
> Sum of elements for column 0 is 7.5 Sum of elements for column 1 is
>   8.0 Sum of elements for column 2 is 7.0 Sum of elements for column 3 is 11.5

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    matrix = [[],[],[]]
    matrix[0].append(raw_input('Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 0:'))
    matrix[1].append(raw_input('Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 1:'))
    matrix[2].append(raw_input('Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 2:'))
    print 'The matrix is:', '\n', matrix[0], '\n', matrix[1], '\n', matrix[2], '\n',   

main()
```

I need help adding the columns together, I might have created the matrix incorrectly
I been using `sum = matrix[0][0][0] + matrix[0][0][2]` 
but it does add them it simply puts the two numbers together.
example: I want 1 + 2
expected answer 3
comes out 12

Is there a way you can add two elements of a list together?

Comment: If 1 + 2 results in 12, you're concatenating strings, not adding integers.  Look at how you're setting values. `'1'` is significantly different than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns a string, so that needs to be processed to some form of number.

A short example which asks for input, splits it via whitespace and makes them a `float`:

```
text = raw_input('row 1: ')
nums = [float(word) for word in text.split()]
```

Also, you don't want to be appending to `matrix = [[],[],[]]` - as you'll end up creating what's in effect a 3 dimensional structure. Change this to `matrix = []`... and use `matrix.append(nums)` each time you've got an input line instead.

You may also want to consider what happens if invalid numbers are entered, or if there's not the required amount of them... But that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    f = lambda x: map(float, raw_input('Enter row %d for matrix of 3X4.\n' %(x)).split())
    matrix = [f(0),f(1),f(2)]
    print map(sum, zip(*matrix))

main()
```

The above code takes a 3X4 matrix as input, and prints the sum over each of the columns.

### Explanation:

If `lambda` sounds daunting, you can use a function instead, say:

```
def rowInput(x):
 return map(float, raw_input('Enter row %d for matrix of 3X4.\n' %(x)).split())
```

and call it like

```
matrix = [rowInput(0), rowInput(1), rowInput(2)]
```

---

The `zip` function here takes one element at a time from each of the rows, and sums them up.

> zip(...)
>       zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]
>
> ```
> Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
> from each of the argument sequences. ...
> ```

`zip(*matrix)` will return `[(col0), (col1), (col2), (col3)]`.

---

The `map` function applies the function in the first argument to each element in the second argument. For instance, `map(sum, zip(*matrix))` is equivalent to `[sum(col0), sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3)]`.

> map(...)
>       map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list
>
> ```
> Return a list of the results of applying the function to the items of
> the argument sequence(s). ...
> ```